# How to install Install-Module in Powershell 4

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have Powershell 4 in a Windows Server 2012R2:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.21616
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

But I cannot use `Install-Module` or `Find-Module` or `Get-InstalledMoule`....

```
Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
```

Neither `Set-PSRepository`.

How can I install this feature for installing other modules that I need?